# UEFI settings won't save and can't boot from USB

Tags: uefi, live-usb

I have a Lenovo G50-30 with InsydeH2O UEFI setup utility/BIOS. I can't change any settings except time and date in setup utility. I can toggle settings, but when I exit the setup (Exit Saving Changes) or save changes and then save, and then enter the setup utility again, all settings are back where they were before I changed them.

Settings are not the default ones, but my configuration before installing Ubuntu, the issue started after installing Ubuntu. I have been using Linux for 10 years and own this notebook 2 years, I never had such a problem.
When trying to boot from USB made using Rufus, Etcher.io or UNETBOOTIN (options that worked before) I get a message EFI USB Device (Generic USB Storage) boot failed. I've tried using four different USB drives and all three ports to rule out hardware and software issues. Only USB I could boot after installing Ubuntu is the Ubuntu Live USB.

I've tried re-flashing BIOS, because that should do a "factory reset", but my BIOS is already newest available version, so update utility won't let me flash.

Because of an unrelated issue I can't boot up Ubuntu, but I have a "working" Windows installation.

Update: I've noticed an error flash on bootup before GRUB starts, too quick to read with naked eye, so I recorded it. It says (i deleted video, so it's paraphrased) bootloader error, reading ≤ubuntu's EFI file>; unknown error; reading ; unknown error
After that GRUB starts

Comment: Perhaps like this user who noticed an option. https://superuser.com/questions/852235/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-10-on-a-new-lenovo-ideapad-g50-70

Comment: Some vendors modify  UEFI to boot by description which is not allowed per UEFI spec. Lenovo rename files
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2302170 See these work arounds. Often Boot-Repair or rEFInd help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 1):

Issue that I (and many other Ubuntu users) was facing is described [in this OMGUbuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/12/ubuntu-corrupting-lenovo-laptop-bios).

A workaround using rEFInd is proposed on [Lenovo forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Y50-70-BIOS-Can-t-Save-Settings-Or-Exit/m-p/3853208#M157885).

Further description of the problem, that seems to be caused by Ubuntu enabling Intel SPI driver that's still in development, is available in this [OMGUbuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/ubuntu-17-10-lenovo-fix).

Solution proposed in the OMGUbuntu article above:

1. Install UKUU - Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility
2. Install Linux 4.14.9
3. Reboot and select Linux 4.14.9 in GRUB
4. Boot fully
5. Shut down
6. Boot to BIOS, should work now

Not really sure why, but I can confirm it works, now I can boot from non-Ubuntu live-USB and change and save UEFI/BIOS settings.